# Apache causing huge load, how to pin down the reason?

Tags: apache-2.2

Apache is using over 100% of my 2 core VPS
see
http://fs1.directupload.net/images/141215/g9s3t8mi.png
Since there are 50+ sites on that server what will be the smartest way to pin down the reason/site?

Suspendnig them one by one and waiting isn't something I would love to do....

Is there a way to see which one is getting the most traffic?

The setup is nginx in front for statit and apache gets everything dynamic
It's a standart VestaCP setup if you are familiar with this control panel
Most of the sites are wordpress with little to low-medium traffic.

Comment: Securing and enabling [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) can help you narrow down the virtualhost and will allow you to use [apachetop](https://github.com/JeremyJones/Apachetop) as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but if most of your traffic comes from users with a history, then rate-throttling connections from new IP addresses is effective and might not be intolerable for users

Answer (score 1):

Is apache logging to different logfiles for each site?  Look in the apache log directory with 'ls -latr' to see which file was updated most recently.  do that a couple of times and you should see the same log growing relatively quickly.  Then look in that log (`tail -f logfilename`) to see what's getting hit.  Usually brute-force login attempts on wordpress; I use custom security to lock down wp-login.php to my own ip addresses and I also recently began to use the wordpress sucuri plugin to monitor login attempts.

in case it might be of use, here's my custom security inserted into wp-login.php after the first "*/" (and needs to be reinstalled after every wordpress update, but helps cut down on what you're seeing by a ton)
(assume my personal computer's ip address is 11.22.33.44)

```
$allowed = array('11.22.33.44','127.0.0.1');

if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]){
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

  if(!in_array($ip, $allowed)){
    print "Sorry but you do not have permission to access this page from $ip";
    exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: very nice idea
Do you know an easy way to limit the access to that on a higher level, maybe at nginx or apache config? 
Because there are 10s of WP sites and also it won't work for new ones

Comment: although i'm sure it's possible, unfortunately I don't know the answer (yet).  My solution has been to create a single file ('ip_security.php') and then 'include' it by adding a single line to every one of my wp sites' wp-login files - very tedious with 20+ so I've been considering making it a plugin or something... but at least this way I can add and remove ips in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It's always WordPress!

Because of how `mod_php` works, it's very difficult to determine which instance is causing the load.

Start by looking for anything obviously load intensive - figure out which ones have the most hits, look for any of them that have development features set like disabling caching.  Add response time to your logs and look for sites which are responding more slowly than others.

If that's fruitless, the best way to track down where to place the blame might be to switch over to separate processes per wordpress instance, using multiple fastcgi backends and PHP-FPM.

Comment: since i'm quite new to this, what would be the easiest way to see which site gets the most traffic?

Comment: @Greg You'll need to be logging it - either by having separate log files per virtual host, or by putting the hostname in the log format.  Check what your current logs look like.